# Completion methods in custom framework

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

My main program is calling a method in my custom framework and I want it to call a method in my main program when complete. What is the best method to do this in Swift?

The method I am calling is a service, so I can't expect it to return quickly.

This is in my framework:

```
public func login(server: String, password: String, username: String, url: String, completion : (success: Bool, json: AnyObject?) -> Void) -> UserProfile {

    completion(success: true, json: json)

    return profile
}
```

This is how I cam calling it from my main program and I think that I am doing it wrong

```
services.login(hostToUse, password:self.passwordField.text!, username: self.emailField.text!, url: "http://\(hostToUse)/user/login", completion: testCompletion())
```

Comment: Share the code. You have to add a completion handler. I'll show you how once you paste the code.

Comment: This is the method in my custom framework. it worked in my main program but moving it over complicated things     public func login(server : String, password : String, username : String, url: String, completion : (success: Bool, json: AnyObject? ) ->Void ) -> UserProfile

Comment: I really cant help you without a proper code. Your question will keep getting downvotes if you dont give proper details I am afraid.

Comment: it edited my main answer. This site is about helping other developers, not worrying about votes.

Comment: In addition to Dershowitz123's answer below, your `login` method appears to be trying to return `UserProfile`. It should not return anything. You should pass the `profile` back as an additional parameter of the closure. Don't rely on properties of your class for this sort of stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling it wrong. call like so:

```
 services.login(hostToUse, password:self.passwordField.text!, username: self.emailField.text!, url: "http://\(hostToUse)/user/login") {(success, jsonData) in

    if success {
        // Your success code here
    }
    else {
        // Your failure code here
    }

}
```

Comment: that is what I needed. that you

Comment: Anytime! Happy coding! :)